# Navigationbar text in not centered on device when using onsen ui

Tags: css, html, onsen-ui

I have downloaded default master-detail template from `onsen ui`, and then developed an cordova mobile application based on it.The header title in navigation bar is centered on pc-browser and chrome ripple, but not on device. On device it will stick to the left. I have add this style to see what is going on.

```
    .navigation-bar__center
    {
        text-align:center;
        border:solid;
        border-width:1px;
    }
    .navigation-bar
    {
        border:solid;
        border-color:#f00;
        border-width:1px;
    }
```

it seems the correspond div for header is not stretched.

this is on pc-browser

[image]

And this is on mobile device (samsung android 4.2)

[image]

ps. the problem exists on all pages.

Comment: @Nima No it didn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `fixed-style` attribute on the navigation bar tag. Like this

```
<ons-toolbar fixed-style>
  <div class="center">
    This will be centered
  </div>
</ons-toolbar>
```

Actually, the reason why it isn't centered on the device is that Onsen UI tries to emulate native behavior. On Android the navigation bar title is not centered, but left-aligned.